# Zoom JPanel in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, zooming

I have an existing `Java Swing` application.  In the middle of the application is a single `JPanel` which I want to be able to `zoom in and out` of.  The `JPanel` has a number of `JComponents` on it (mostly other `JPanels` and `JLabels`).

Also `mouse` position will need to be adjusted appropriately as well - so `mouseevents` need to remain same even after the `JPanel` has been zoomed.  As such simply changing the `paint` methods of each `component` doesn't seem plausible.

**EDIT:**

[image]

OK i kind of got it working using the `MagnifierUI` `class` with some minor edits.  However the magnified panel I create has the wrong `mouseevents` - i.e. the panel is scaled, `mouseevents` are not.

Comment: JXLayer can do this.  Getting hold of an example (or even JXLayer itself) is problematic now days

Comment: I should mention, I have tried the following methods 1) [Utils4Swing5](http://javadeveloperslife.wordpress.com/2009/07/18/zooming-swing/) which does not work at all.  2) I have also attempted Peit Blok's method using JXLayer and PBTransform - however Peit Blok appears to have left the planet and I can no longer find the jar necessary for PBTransform [link](http://www.java.net/node/700255)

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"*  Leave this to user choice of screen resolution or the OS' inbuilt screen magnification utility.  If the user needs it, they'll know where to find it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer yep I have tried using JXLayer (and JLayer) but TransformUI appears to be the only UI class that can be used with JXLayer to zoom and it is strangely absent from the internet (as Peit Blok, its developer, appears to have shut up shop)

Comment: I've had it packaged it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/re1hmvypp19oqy1/JXLayer-PBJar-Demo.zip). Check out the `TestWrapped` demo in PB's Jar...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sweet! I'll give it a try, report back later today - exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

This is just a scetch:

- in your `JPanel` keep track of an [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) which represents the scale factor (see `AffineTransform.scale(double,double)`,
- override the `paint` method of your `JPanel`: before calling `super.paint` apply the affine transformation to your `Graphics2D` object (cast from the parameter of the `paint` method) by calling `Graphics2D.setTransform(AffineTransform)`, call `super.paint` afterwards
- override the methods `processMouseEvent`, `processMouseMotionEvent` and `processMouseWheelEvent`, apply the affine transformation to the coordinates of their mouse event parameter (`AffineTransform.transform(java.awt.geom.Point2D,java.awt.geom.Point2D)`), call respective `super`-method afterwards.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try SwingUtilities.convertPoint(source, point,destination);