# Zoom in and zoom out function in Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have to add `Zoom In and Zoom Out` functionality to `JPanel`, which contains components like `JLabel` with `ImageIcon`.

I want to `Zoom JPanel` with their components appropriately 
I tried with following code snippet but it did not work properly.

The `JPanel` which is having `null` layout and is itself placed inside an `Applet`.
I am unsure of the reason as to why it is not working either because of `Applet` or something else !!

`cPanel` is my `JPanel` which contains `JLabel`

Following code snippet on Zoom `Button` click,
it shows blink screen on button click after that as original

```
Graphics g = cPanel.getGraphics();
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
AffineTransform savedXForm = g2d.getTransform();
g2d.scale(1.0, 1.0);
g2d.setColor(Color.red);
super.paint(g);
g2d.setTransform(savedXForm);
cPanel.validate();
cPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: *"i want to zoom in and zoom"* I want questions to be easy to read.  Please stop 'mumbling' add an upper case letter to the start of sentences.

Comment: I'd take a look at your layout issues, then I'd take a look `JXLayer`

Comment: See ***[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944442/zoom-in-java-swing-application?rq=1)*** post

Comment: @ExtremeCoders +1 for suggestion, shame the links are broken... ;)

Comment: Please anyone tell me what i did wrong, is there any other solution to do it or it not possible in applet because of null layout i set to jpanel

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into this link:
http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2015/04/zoom-in-and-zoom-out-image-using-mouse_9.html#.Vz6iG-QXV0w

Source Code to Refer(Here it has been accomplished using MouseWheelListener):

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import com.mortennobel.imagescaling.ResampleOp;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ImageZoom {

    private JFrame frmImageZoomIn;
    private static final String inputImage = "C:\\my-pfl-pic.jpg"; // give image path here
    private JLabel label = null; 
    private double zoom = 1.0;  // zoom factor
    private BufferedImage image = null;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ImageZoom window = new ImageZoom();
                    window.frmImageZoomIn.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public ImageZoom() throws IOException {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private void initialize() throws IOException {
        frmImageZoomIn = new JFrame();
        frmImageZoomIn.setTitle("Image Zoom In and Zoom Out");
        frmImageZoomIn.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmImageZoomIn.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        frmImageZoomIn.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        image = ImageIO.read(new File(inputImage));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // display image as icon 
        Icon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(inputImage);
        label = new JLabel( imageIcon );
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panel.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                int notches = e.getWheelRotation();
                double temp = zoom - (notches * 0.2);
                // minimum zoom factor is 1.0
                temp = Math.max(temp, 1.0);
                if (temp != zoom) {
                    zoom = temp;
                    resizeImage();
                }
            }
        });
        scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
    }

    public void resizeImage() {
           System.out.println(zoom);
           ResampleOp  resampleOp = new ResampleOp((int)(image.getWidth()*zoom), (int)(image.getHeight()*zoom));
               BufferedImage resizedIcon = resampleOp.filter(image, null);
           Icon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(resizedIcon);
           label.setIcon(imageIcon);
        }


}
```